# Why is the additive group of rational numbers indecomposable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A group $G$ is *indecomposable* if $G \neq \langle e \rangle$ and $G$ cannot be written as the direct product of two of its proper subgroups. Why is the additive group of rational numbers $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ indecomposable?

Comment: Additional group?!!

Comment: what do you mean by "decomposition"?

Answer (score 13):

I suspect, what you want to ask is why $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is [indecomposable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_module), ie. it cannot be written as the direct sum of two subgroups.

The answer is that two non-trivial subgroups must intersect non-trivially. If $\{0\}\neq H, K < \mathbb{Q}$, then choose non-zero $p/q \in H, a/b\in K$, then
$$
qa\frac{p}{q} = ap = pb\frac{a}{b} \in H\cap K\setminus \{0\}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Prahalad Vaidyanathn

Comment: Why can one be sure that $qa \frac{p} {q} \in H$?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are asking why the additive group $Q$ of rationals is not a non-trivial direct sum.

If it were, then the projection on one of the direct summands would be a non-trivial idempotent in the endomorphism ring of $Q$. But [the endomorphism ring of $Q$ is isomorphic to the *ring* of rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). This is a field, so it has only the trivial idempotents 0, 1.

Answer (score -3):

Because there are no additive primes. Every number is the sum of two other nontrivial numbers.